# RTK Query Pattern for fetching data with query arguments

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I have an application where multiple components are fetching data like below and is using the data for some rendering.

```
const {data} = useGetUserQuery({shippingAddressId: 123});
```

I'm trying to figure out what is the normal RTK query pattern if I wanted to call `useGetUserQuery` with a new `shippingAddressId` and have all the components consuming this hook rerender?

Since RTK Query uses the query parameters as cache keys, the data doesn't update since the `shippingAddressId` is hardcoded.

I'm currently getting around this by `dispatching` an action to the redux store which updates a `params` object with say `shippingAddressId` and using that as my query argument in the `useGetUserQuery({...params})` hook.

By dispatching an action, all my components that are consuming the `useGetUserQuery` hook gets updated.

Is this an anti-pattern?

Thank you and I look forward to any recommendations.

Comment: That's perfectly fine.

Answer (score 3):

As you can read from the [redux toolkit query documentation](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/overview#use-hooks-in-components):

> RTK Query will automatically fetch data on mount, re-fetch when parameters change, provide {data, isFetching} values in the result, and re-render the component as those values change.

So yes, that's how RTKQuery handles the update and the re-fetch, you should use a variable instead of a hardcoded number.